# HTML Button Opens Youtube Video

Tags: javascript, html, ytplayer

I'm new to HTML so maybe this is easy/simple to answer. I'm trying to popup a youtube video to full screen when the user clicks on a button on my html script. I'm familiar with the youtube player API and javascript but I'm not sure how to make this happen through HTML (I've done it with iOS). Any advice on how to implement this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create code like this

```
<a href="#" id="fix-fullscreen">Full screen</a>
```

and create `<script>` with javascript

```
var fullscreen = document.getElementById('fix-fullscreen'),
    player = document.getElementById('player');

fullscreen.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (~player.src.indexOf('?')) player.src += '&autoplay=1';
    else player.src += '?autoplay=1';

    var req = player.requestFullscreen
        || player.webkitRequestFullscreen
        || player.mozRequestFullScreen
        || player.msRequestFullscreen;

    req.call(player);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Hope it help.

Comment: Where do i add the first line of code? And how do I call this from a button click? I have `<div id="buttonSection">
<button type="button" onclick="popup()" style="width:310px";"height=75px">Play Video
</button>` so far... Just don't know where your snippet comes into play... Thanks!

Comment: add something like this `<button id="fix-fullscreen"` and then insert the javascript code inside `<script>here</script>` tag

Comment: Sorry, if you need fullscreen you don't need set to popup window.

Comment: What function does onClick call? And the js code you gave me should have the ytplayer api in there too? Thanks

Comment: `onclick`  event occurs when the user clicks on an element, in this example is when you click `button`. no need youtube API for js code. try placing all the code I provided into html you have with embedded youtube video.

Comment: Forgive me if this is obvious but where do I put the embedded youtube video?